# How to split only if delimiter is present?

Tags: javascript

I want to split a URL only if it has query parameters.  When I do something like this;

```
var url = window.location.href;
var somevalue = url.split("?");
```

somevalue has the URL value even if "?" is not there.  Is there a way to split only if the delimiter is there?  Meaning, as a single or one line function rather than indexof() or something similar?

Comment: No there is not, unless you write it. How would such a function work? Return an array if delimiter is present, otherwise the original string? What is the result you want?

Comment: How about some `if` ?

Comment: What exactly should be stored in `somevalue` if the delimiter does not appear?

Comment: I think you might find [this diagram of link anatomy](http://bl.ocks.org/abernier/3070589) useful.

Comment: @FelixKling: Empty string would be nice.  So I guess the next check is .IndexOf("?") and then another on that for value > 0?  What a convoluted way to do what should be a simple check.

Comment: Well, you could write `var somevalue = url.indexOf('?')  > -1 ? url.split("?") : '';`

Comment: that works!  Thanks.  Post as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that should work:

```
function getSplit()
{
   var somevalue;
   var url = window.location.href;
   if(url.indexOf("?") != -1)
   {
       //your code here
       somevalue = url.split("?");
   }
   else
   {
        somevalue = "";
   }
   return somevalue;
}
```

Call the one line function:

```
var url = getSplit();
```

Comment: Did you read the question? *"Meaning, as a single or one line function rather than indexof() or something similar?"*.

Answer (score 0):

try regexp

```
/\?(.*)/.exec(url);
```

it return null (when no ?) or array (element with index 1 is after ?)